# Search for files modifed on certain Date and Time range

Tags: windows-xp, search

I am trying to search for files modified on a certain date between a certain time, it doesn't seem to allow searching by time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with the [Advanced Query Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx) that comes with [Windows Search 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/windowssearch4.mspx?tab=Install%20It):

> To specify a date range, type the property followed by two dates.

So, for example:

```
modified:11/05/06..11/05/07
```

There are [videos from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/overview/videos.mspx) that have a few tips on using the search tools too.

---

Actually, you might want to take a look at our recent blog post from Tom Wijsman on Windows Search: [Digging Deeper: Searching in Windows](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/23/digging-deeper-windows/).