# How to search in windows according to access date

Tags: windows-7, search, date

I have found only according to "date modified" and not "access date"

I haven't found any ways of sorting this correctly. Maybe I should use third party software?

Comment: Can't tell exactly, but maybe this helps: [Windows Search Advanced Query Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx), also see [my other answer](http://superuser.com/questions/301697/search-for-files-modifed-on-certain-date-and-time-range/301698#301698) here.

Comment: Do you have access to powershell on the machine where you want to search?

Comment: Ooops...just saw the Windows-7 tag, so you do have access to powershell.

Comment: It seems that LastAccessTime is disabled by default in newer operating systems. To enabled you'll need to modify ntfsdisabledastaccessupdate registry key from 1 to 0 on the system where files are and then reboot it. path is HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Powershell (which is already installed on your Windows 7 machine) you could do something like this:

```
Get-childItem C:\* -recurse -include *.txt | Where-Object{$_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)}
```

This would recursively search the C drive for any text file accessed in the last 7 days for example.